# Using TortoiseSVN, how do I revert to a previous revision?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I can't seem to get this right, can someone help me with the steps for this. Trunk is at revision 100 and I want Trunk in SVN to be reverted back to revision 98.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html

Tortoise Menu -> Show Logs, right click on Revision and then Context Menu -> Revert

Comment: And then commit, presumably?

Comment: Menu option doesn't exist.